# How Can I open websocket port on azure?

Tags: azure, websocket, port, livechat

I want to create live chatroom by [BrainSocket](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket).I follow from [this tutorial](https://xuri.me/2014/09/08/laravel-4-real-time-chat.html) ,and it's work well on my localhost.When i deploy on ubuntu 14.04 on azure virtual machine it not work.
Chrome Inspect is tell me error on this part of my code

```
 app.BrainSocket = new BrainSocket(
                    new WebSocket('ws://myappname.cloudapp.net:8080'),
                    new BrainSocketPubSub()
            );
```

it's tell ws://myappname.cloudapp.net:8080 is return 404 not found... 
I guess it should be web socket port problem on Azure. How can I open web socket port 8080 on Azure virtual machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an Endpoint to your virutal machine. Go to Management Portal/Your_VM/Endpoints and click add new. Your endpoint configuration should look similar to this:

[image]

Detailed instruction can be found here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/