# How to open websocket for Azure Windows VM

Tags: java, azure, websocket, socket.io

I have added 9094 to the endpoint and trying to access xxx.cloudapp.net:9094/socktio.... But I am still not able to hit this with the client deployed on my lapton. I keep getting connection timedout error, although the server starts properly without error. I am using java language and run this program as a standalone java application

```
[main] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer - Session store /     pubsub factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer - SocketIO server started at port: 9094
```

Just tagging these questions which doesnot solve the problem yet
[How Can I open websocket port on azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872643/how-can-i-open-websocket-port-on-azure)

Comment: Could you provide more information about your question, such as your code. or you could try this URL https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal/

Comment: I am running a google speech to text api server on this machine. Basically trying to test their java streaming code.  This works fine, but i need to run it on the cloud. The code can be found here. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, this issue may be due to the wrong firewall config. You could create a NSG which controls both inbound and outbound traffic of your VM.

The following steps may be useful for you.

1.You could create a Network Security Group.

1)Select the resource group where the VM resides, then click the Add button.
[image]

2)To search the Network security group in the search bar.
[image]

3)Input some parameters to create a new NSG.
[image]

2.You could add an inbound security rule in the NSG.

1)Select the Network security group which you have created and click the Add button.
[image]

2)input some parameters to create a new inbound security rule.
[image]

3.You could associate your Network Security Group with a subnet or a specific network interface.
1)Select the NSG which you have created and click the Associate button.
[image]

2)Select your virtual network and then select the appropriate subnet.
[image]

The reference:
    https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal/

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It still doesnt allow me to connect. I do have another webserver running at 8080. I am able to connect to that using telnet. But just for this one I am not able to connect even after adding the nsg

Comment: you can change your webserver port from 8080 to 9094 and then restart your webserver. if you can access just like accessing the tomcat front page, that indicates you can access the port 9094. I think that there is no service on the port 9094, so you get the error.

Comment: When i try to start the java server on xxx.cloudapp.net 9094 it throws error saying [main] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer - Session store / pubsub
factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested addre
ss: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun

Comment: I cannot user localhost or 127.0.0.1 as this will open only to local processes. So i need a way to start the server on DNS.

Comment: You can use IP access method just like accessing http://104.210.152.141:9094/. If you can access your URL by using IP+Port, that indicates you can access the port 9094. If so, you can ask some questions about how to config DNS access to Azure VM. This URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099369/mapping-dns-to-azure-vm will be useful.

Comment: Actually I got it resolved. The way i was starting the server was wrong. i was starting it as localhost:9094 instead of 0.0.0.0:9094. Such a small thing that made difference

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of issues i had. one was obviously was resolved by @johnny above. I am sure that made some difference.
second issue was the way i started the server on Azure windows vm. Instead of starting it as 0.0.0.0 9094 i was trying to start as 127.0.0.1 or localhost. This resolved the issue I had with socket server running on windows azure vm.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience

1. Open port 9094 Inbound security rule on Machine-nsg on Azure
2. Open port 9094 on VM firewall inbound rule

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).